# How to provide Inputs and Output for dynamic components

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-dynamic-components, ng-component-outlet

I ran into [ng-dynamic-component](https://github.com/gund/ng-dynamic-component) package, while struggling with Angular's `ngComponentOutlet` unacheiveable `@Input`s and `@Output`s interactions.

In my application, I'd like to dynamically instantiate different types of tab components in `*ngFor`.

Reading [ng-dynamic-component](https://github.com/gund/ng-dynamic-component) documentation, interacting with `@Input`s and `@Output`s isn't being dont in the HTML template, instead, in the component implementation itself.

Considering the fact I need to run over all of my tabs, each tab needs to get different `@Input` and subscribe with different data to `@Output`s based on its' instance, e.g,

```
<ndc-dynamic *ngFor="let tab of tabs"
              [ndcDynamicComponent]="component"
              [ndcDynamicInputs]="inputs" <!-- this needs to be different for each tab-->
              [ndcDynamicOutputs]="outputs"> <!-- this needs to be different for each tab-->
</ndc-dynamic>
```

Except for corrupting my tab object with `inputs` and `outputs` member, or creating a special interface such as :

```
interface DynamicTab {
  tab: Tab,
  inputs: any,
  outputs: any
}
```

Any idea how to implement such behavior? some way to make good use of the `*ngFor` and manipulate the basic `inputs` with the current tab?

I could create two methods on my component to calculate the needed inputs and outputs, but all fo these options seem to be too much work to manipulate the current `tab` data i already have while running with the `*ngFor`

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

I have the next:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" label="{{tab.label}}">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="tab.component;injector:createInjector(tab.data)"></ng-container>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

The tabs is a array object with my differents component, each component is put in each tab.

it is my model about tab:

```
export interface CwcTabModel {
  label?: string;
  component?: any;
  data?: CwcDataTab;
}


export class CwcDataTab {
  data?: any;
}
```

CwcDataTab is the data to send to each component and with the injector is when pass data.

And now you can create a Test component, for instance:

TestTabOneComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-tab-one',
  templateUrl: './test-tab-one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-tab-one.component.scss']
})
export class TestTabOneComponent implements OnInit {

  information: string;

  constructor(private dataTab: CwcDataTab) {
   if (this.dataTab !== undefined && this.dataTab.data !== undefined) {
     this.information = this.dataTab.data;
   }
  }

}
```

Then for use the component tabs you can create in some component the object tabs:

```
tabs = [
  {
    label: 'TAB1',
    component: TestTabOneComponent, /* it will be a dynamic component, but data should be different*/
    data: {
      data: 'value1 valor distinto, mismo componente'
    }
  },
  {
    label: 'TAB2',
    component: TestTabOneComponent, /* it will be a dynamic component, but data should be different*/
    data: {
      data: 'value2 valor distinto, mismo componente'
    }
  },
{
    label: 'TAB3',
    component: TestTabOneComponent, /* it will be a dynamic component, but data should be different*/
    data: {
      data: 'value3 valor distinto, mismo componente'
    }
  }
];
```

And each tabs use the same component (can be generic component) and in each component you can see the different data. 
sorry my english, I hope you can use that.